# Case Statement, Like operator in SQL

Tags: sql, database, case, sql-like

I have multiple rows in the table (as in the image). I need to make a new column from specific keywords extracted from the strings.

[image]

| Title | Output |
| --- | --- |
| Ad - LA - [Ke] [NC] [W] Test for IPHIndi | W |
| [MWeb] My Ads Center (Batch 3) Part 2 | Mweb |
| Ad - LA [NC] [W+MWeb] My Ads Center | W+MWeb |
| Ad - LA [NC] [WZ+K] My Ads Center | Others |
| Ad - LA [NC] [W+MWeb] My Ads Center | Mweb |
| [M] WMy Ads Center (Batch 3) Part 2 | M |

I tried using case statement

```sql
CASE 
    WHEN title LIKE '%W+MWeb%' THEN 'w+m'
    WHEN title LIKE '%MWeb%' THEN 'MWeb'
    WHEN title LIKE '%W%' THEN 'w'
    WHEN title LIKE '%M%' THEN 'M'
    ELSE 'OTHER'
END AS MARKER
```

However, I am getting incorrect data as sometimes if we have any letter as M, it is marking it as M which is incorrect and is there any way where I can search using the square brackets?

Please help me out and thank you

Comment: Why `[W]` and not `[Ke]` or `[NC]`? Why `[W+MWeb]` in one case, but `[MWeb]` in a seemingly identical case?

Comment: apologies for the incomplete picture,  the requirement that i need to group a string in only 4 categories , W, M , Mweb or w+m.

If a sting have a keyword [W+MWeb] then group it in w+m,
If a sting have a keyword [MWeb] then group it in MWeb,

and so on

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you need to escape the square brackets as they act as a wildcard operator to specify a range.

Usually it's done with \ before the character you want to escape but might depend on the types of database.

This might be helpful, good luck

[escaping square brackets in SQL](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-escape-square-brackets-in-a-like-clause-in-sql-server/#:%7E:text=Square%20brackets%5B%5D%2C%20is%20among,using%20one%20more%20square%20bracket)

Comment: Values with brackets are not used as patterns for `like` here.

Comment: Thank you @blake it does work,  For the reference i am pasting the code below

`CASE 
 WHEN LQ.title LIKE '%\[W+MWeb]%' ESCAPE '\' THEN 'w+m'
 WHEN LQ.title LIKE '%\[MWeb]%' ESCAPE '\' THEN 'MWeb'
 WHEN LQ.title LIKE '%\[W]%' ESCAPE '\'THEN 'w'
 WHEN LQ.title LIKE '%\[M]%' ESCAPE '\' THEN 'M'
    ELSE 'OTHER'
END AS MARKER`